# Is it possible to achieve Single sign-on with Keycloak having AD FS as identity provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid, adfs

I have integrated my angular app to allow users to login through their AD account. I have followed [this](https://www.keycloak.org/2017/03/how-to-setup-ms-ad-fs-30-as-brokered.html) article for the integration of AD FS with Keycloak.

I have integrated SSO with AD FS without Keycloak in past. Now I am unable to figure out how to achieve SSO when Keycloak is added in between the angular app and ADFS. I am always prompted for my AD username/password even though I have already signed in to another application webpage using the same AD account in a browser.

I want to know how to achieve SSO in this context and whether it is even possible to have SSO in such cases.